# Why is Spring JPA merging and copying a new child object during a parent update, and then setting the child properties to null?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I upgrading an old batch app to Spring 5 from Spring 2 or 3. There is a parent-child object relationship where the parent and one child have been retrieved from the database, a new child has been added, and when the parent is saved with a repository.save(), it's throwing this error:

```
not-null property references a null or transient value
```

I've debugged it, and it seems that a merge is happening in the stack trace on the save(), and in that process, the new child is being deleted or copied and a new one with all null properties is added back to the collection, which is causing the error.

What is causing this merge and copy?

Here are the relevant bits of the related entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DOC_DLVR")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="DOC_DLVR_CHNL_CD",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
abstract public class  DocDlvr {
...
    private Set<DocDlvrActy> docDlvrActy = new HashSet<DocDlvrActy>();

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="DOC_DLVR_ID", nullable=false)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
    public Set<DocDlvrActy> getDocDlvrActy() {
        return docDlvrActy;
    }
}


@Entity 
@Table(name = "DOC_DLVR_ACTY")
public class DocDlvrActy {
....
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "DOC_DLVR_ACTY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getDocDlvrActyId() {
        return docDlvrActyId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOC_DLVR_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public DocDlvr getDocDlvr() {
        return docDlvr;
    }
    public void setDocDlvr(DocDlvr docDlvr) {
        this.docDlvr = docDlvr;
    }

}
```

Here's the code that actually calls the save/update:

```
docDlvr.setDlvrStatCd(docDeliveryStatusEnum);
docDlvr.setUpdtId(publishDocVO.getUserId());

DocDlvrActy docDlvrActy = new DocDlvrActy();
docDlvrActy.setDocDlvr(docDlvr);
docDlvrActy.setActyCd(docActyTypeEnum);
docDlvrActy.setCreaId(publishDocVO.getUserId());
docDlvrActy.setCreateTimeStamp(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
docDlvr.getDocDlvrActy().add(docDlvrActy);

returnedMailBO.updateDocDlvr(docDlvr);
```

The returnedMailBO is just a service layer. It goes thru that and another one before hitting the final one that calls the repo and saves it:

```
Timestamp now = new Timestamp((new java.util.Date()).getTime());
docDlvr.setUpdtTimeStamp(now);

docDlvrRepository.save(docDlvr);
```

Yes, I'm setting the reference back to the parent DocDlvr object in the new DocDlvrActy child object. Have done some searching here, and looks like it has something to do with a detached child from the persistence context?

I haven't added any explicit annotations or configuration for Transactions, so whatever is default is being used.
This is during a batch process, so maybe there should be some saves, flushes, etc. It's been awhile since I've gotten this much into Spring Data Jpa.

We are using Java 8, Spring 5.3.29, Spring Boot 2.7.16. I'm just trying to using basic Spring Boot to wire up the context, even though it's a simple batch job. Yes, have looked into Spring Batch a bit, am not using it.

Comment: Show the code you are calling that hits the problem. Note though that you only have cascade persist on your docDlvrActy relationship. By saving an existing DocDlvr (using merge) the merge is not cascaded and might be why JPA (hibernate?) is creating a stub entity for the managed instance since it doesn't exist yet. You might try explicitly calling save on the DocDlvrActy instance and using what is returned in the docDlvrActy set.

Comment: added the code; I guess I'm not familiar with this merge, or why it's doing it; this seems like a simple, common operation, saving the child objects when the parent object is saved; I would have thought the new child object would simply be saved and the parentId updated;

Comment: just to be clear, I'm not explicitly calling merge(); I just saw it in the stack when debugging

Comment: Spring will check if it can tell if the entity is new or existing and call either em.persist or em.merge. I don't know why it bothers as JPA will do the same thing if you just directly call em.merge, and the two api have slightly different mechanics - Springs implementation causes issues when passing in a new entity that references an existing one, as persist throws exceptions when given a detached instance.

Answer (score 0):

The JPA spec states, section 3.2.7.1:

> If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y,
> where cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL is not specified, then navigation
> of the same association from X' yields a reference to a managed object
> Y' with the same persistent identity as Y.

I would have suspected the intent was that Y' would have all the values of Y set, but they are only required to make a copy that shares the ID, which is what you are getting.

Options I see:

1. Add new instance after saving the parent DocDlvr.
2. Add CascadeType.MERGE to the relationship
3. Manually call save on the child instance and use that reference in the DocDlvr's set.

Comment: Note that not all JPA providers will behave that way

Comment: Adding CascadeType.MERGE seemed to fix it, although I'm still confused as to why. I thought this merged the child to the parent persistence context, but when merge() is explicitly called. I still don't see why I need to do this for a new child object that's attached to a managed parent, but I guess that's it...Thanks.

Comment: You are calling merge (via the save call) on X. It takes all the data in your entity X (DocDlvr?) and merges into a managed instance X', copying all state as required. When it gets to your docDlvrActy set, since you don't have cascade set, for each Y in the set it will put in empty Y' instance with the ID set (or use the managed instance of Y' if one is already loaded) - it just needs the ID for FK operations. By adding cascade merge, you are telling JPA that all state within every referencing in the docDlvrActy also needs to be merged.

Comment: Cascade merge might be what you want and expect to have happen when there is a new instance added, but you'll have to be careful as if this collection references stale DocDlvrActy in the future; what you give this method will entirely overwrite what is in the DB.